# Sending a table as an email, only displaying first row

Tags: php, html, sql, email, laravel-5

i am working on sending batch emails, however when formatting the table i get the table headers and only one row of data from the table, i have tried using php to loop through and display all rows (total of 10) but i am not having any luck, Help appreciated.

```
<?php

$db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=website4.0;host=localhost", "root", "");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$query = ("SELECT * FROM students, criteria_table, email, buildtable ");

$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();

    while($row = $statement->fetch()) {
        $id = $row['studentID'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $studentID = $row['studentID'];
        $title = $row['Title'];
        $heading1 = $row['Heading1'];
        $heading2 = $row['Heading2'];
        $heading3 = $row['Heading3'];
        $heading4 = $row['Heading4'];
        $subject =$row['subject'];
        $setfrom =$row['setfrom'];
        $yourname=$row['your_name'];
        $criteria=$row['Criteria'];
        $description=$row['Description'];
        $mark=$row['Mark'];


        sendEmail($id, $email, $title, $heading1, $heading2, $heading3, 
        $heading4, $name, $studentID, $subject, $setfrom, $yourname, 
        $criteria, $description, $mark);

    }
```

This is the function i am calling to try and build the table:

```
<?
function sendEmail($id, $email, $title, $heading1, $heading2, 
$heading3, $heading4, $name, $studentID, $subject, $setfrom, 
$yourname, $criteria, $description, $mark)
{
    $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer(true);

    $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=website4.0;host=localhost", "root", "");
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $query = ("SELECT * FROM buildtable, criteria_table");

    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $values = $statement->fetchAll();


    foreach($values as $row){
        $tit = $row['Title'];
        $heading1 = $row['Heading1'];
        $heading2 = $row['Heading2'];
        $heading3 = $row['Heading3'];
        $heading4 = $row['Heading4'];
    }


    foreach($values as $row){
        $htmlversion=
        "<h1>".$tit."</h1>Name: ".$name."<br>ID: ".$id."<br><table><tr>
        <th>".$heading1."</th><th>".$heading2."</th><th>".$heading3."</th>
        <th>".$heading4."</th></tr> <tr><td>".$row['Criteria']."</td>
        <td>".$row['Description']."</td><td>".$row['Mark']."</td></tr>";
    }



    $textVersion = "Hi ".$name.",.\r\n ".
        "This is your StudentID: ".$studentID."text Version";
    // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->isSMTP();                                             
    // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->Host = ' smtp.mailtrap.io';                                  
    // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                                
    // SMTP username
    $mail->Username = 'b74afc48436e94';                       
    // SMTP password
    $mail->Password = '90b37082eab90a';                      
    // TCP port to connect to
    $mail->Port = 25;                                   
    $mail->setFrom($setfrom, $yourname);
    // Name is optional
    $mail->addAddress($email);               
    // Add 
    //$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         
    // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body    = $htmlversion;
    $mail->AltBody = $textVersion;

    if(!$mail->send()) {
            echo 'Message could not be sent.';
            echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } 
    else {
        echo 'Message has been sent to Username : '.$name
            .' Email: '.$email.'<br><br>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You're outputting a new table that's missing the closing table tag on each iteration. Check your generated HTML and you might see the issue.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Hi yes i have amended that however it is only displaying the last row of records from the database which consists of 10 records

Comment: You need to study up on Laravel, you do not use PDO use Query Builder / Eloquent, you do not use <table> use markdown emails instead...

Comment: Hi, yes i am aware of that but my emailing contains complex branching and are sent in batches/bulk, hence found this way eaiser- mind you this way deos work for my other functionality but i cant get my head around filing the table up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there is some really big mistake in you code :

```
SELECT * FROM students, criteria_table, email, buildtable
```

Is probably not what you want...

It'll make a Cartesian join of your table (aka for `A,B` / `1,2,3` you'll have `A1,A2,A3,B1,B2,B3`). You'll need to specify a join condition with `ON` like `select from T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.id = T2.t1_id`.

Next, using `foreach` twice on the same array is probably not what you want too...

Try this to understand how it work :

```
$htmlversion = '';

foreach($values as $row){
    $htmlversion .=
        "<h1>".$row['Title']."</h1>Name: ".$row['name']."<br>ID: ".$row['studentID']."<br><table><tr>
        <th>".$row['Heading1']."</th><th>".$row['Heading2']."</th><th>".$row['Heading3']."</th>
        <th>".$row['Heading4']."</th></tr> <tr><td>".$row['Criteria']."</td>
        <td>".$row['Description']."</td><td>".$row['Mark']."</td></tr></table>";
}
```

And last, as said by Kyslik, if you're using Laravel, you should probably avoid doing all of this by hand...

Comment: Great, thanks for claryfying the cartesian join, i have experienced this problem before with no clue as what to make of it Great! problem solved!!!